# Which snap point is used by scroll-snap-type proximity?

Tags: css, scroll

When using the `scroll-snap-type` property with the strictness value `proximity`, which value and which unit are used to determine the snap point? [From what I can see](https://jsfiddle.net/berlinersueden/ohzq542f/), it seems to be something around the lines of `30vh`, however, [this is not documented](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scroll-snap-1/).

Comment: It's actually documented that it's not universal. It depends on the user agent, so my guess is that it's probably different for each browser. Would be nice if someone tested it though :)